# Как получить P-value с помощью Python?

Tags: python, статистика, scipy

Необходимо рассчитать P-value через хи-квадрат.
Выполняю на питоне данных код

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
c = chisquare([0,4,7,5],ddof=2)
print(c)
```

и получаю

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=6.5, pvalue=0.010787449254670376)
```

однако при расчете p-value на онлайн сервисах результат получается отличным от того что в результате выполнения моей программы.
Почему так? Может это не то p-value?
В сервисах я рассчитываю с уже готовым хи-квадратом = 6,5.

Comment: А какое оно должно быть на самом деле? Вы считали это значение руками, пользуясь формулами из справочника?

Comment: Что получается у Вас, что получается в сервисах?